# I have two objects and i need to merge them and concat strings if two props have the same key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have two objects and i need to merge them and concat strings if two props have the same key
note: I'm using lodash.js

```js
obj1 = {
  name: 'john', 
  address: 'cairo'
}

obj2 = {
  num : '1', 
  address: 'egypt'
}
```

I need the merged object to be like:

```js
merged = {name:"john", num: "1", address:"cairo,Egypt"}
```

the issue with address prop when I'm trying to use
_.defaults(obj1,obj2)
or
_.merge(obj1,obj2)

the address value will be the value of the address prop inside obj2
so I need a way to merge the two objects and concat the two address props in each object.

Comment: What if your `address` value already has commas? Then how will you know from the merged string what its original parts were? Why not use an array of strings?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Nlg7ew) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Unless you truly want to capitalize the first letter in the appended string you should consider fixing up the example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    function merge(obj1, obj2) {
      let merged = {
        ...obj1,
        ...obj2
      };
      Object.keys(obj1).filter(k => obj2.hasOwnProperty(k)).forEach((k) => {
        merged[k] = obj1[k] + "," + obj2[k]
      })
      return merged
    }

    obj1 = {
      name: 'john',
      address: 'cairo'
    }

    obj2 = {
      num: '1',
      address: 'egypt'
    }

    console.log(merge(obj1, obj2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `lodash`. You can easily create you own function for that. You can do it like this:

- `new Set` - to find all unique **keys** across both input objects
- `for...of` - to iterate over unique keys calculated above

```js
function mergeObjects(obj1, obj2) {
  let merged = {};
  for (const property of [...new Set([...Object.keys(obj1),...Object.keys(obj2)])]) {
    if(obj1[property]) merged[property] = obj1[property];
    if(obj2[property]) merged[property] = merged[property] ? `${merged[property]},${obj2[property]}` : obj2[property];
  }
  return merged;
}

const obj1 = { name: 'john', address: 'cairo' };
const obj2 = { num : '1', address: 'egypt' };

const mergedObj = mergeObjects(obj1, obj2);
console.log(mergedObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mergeObjects(objArr) {
    const newObj = {};

    objArr.forEach((element) => {
        const keys = Object.keys(element);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
            if (newObj[key]) newObj[key] = newObj[key] + "," + element[key];
            else newObj[key] = element[key];
        });
    });
    return newObj;
}

const obj1 = {name: 'john',   address: 'cairo'}

const obj2 = {  num : '1',   address: 'egypt'}
console.log(mergeObjects([obj1, obj2]));
```

This way you can merge any number of objects!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.mergeWith()` to concat the values of specific keys to arrays, and then use `_.mapValues()` to join the arrays to strings:

```js
const { mergeWith, mapValues, uniq, join } = _;

const fn = (predicate, ...objs) => mapValues(
  // merge the objects
  mergeWith(
    {}, 
    ...objs, 
    // handle the keys that you want to merge in a uniqe way
    (a = [], b = [], key) => predicate(key) ? a.concat(b) : undefined
  ),
  // transform the relevant keys' values to a uniqe strings
  (v, key) => predicate(key) ? uniq(v).join(', ') : v
);

const obj1 = { name: 'john', address: 'cairo' };
const obj2 = { num : '1', address: 'egypt' };

const result = fn(key => key === 'address', obj1, obj2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```